# SendGrid throws "Error while copying content to a stream"

Tags: c#, sendgrid, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm creating a Core 2.1 solution in Visual Studio 2017 where I send emails via Sendgrid. When trying to send an email via `SendGrid`, I get the following error:

> **An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**
>
> IOException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync() HttpRequestException: Error
>   while copying content to a stream.
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task
>   serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)

Here is what my code looks like. I'm entering the following in parameters:

**recipients**: list containing "****@gmail.com"

**Subject:** "Hello"

**Body:** Html generated via Heml. It compiles in an online editor without problem.

```
private async Task<bool> SendAsync(List<string> recipients, string subject, string body)
{
    var client = new SendGridClient(this.configuration["Sendgrid:ApiKey"]);  
    var from = new EmailAddress( 
                       this.configuration["Administration:MainEmailAddress"],
                       this.configuration["Administration:MainEmailName"]);  
    var tos = await GetRecipientsForEnvironment(recipients);  
    var message = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(
                                                          from, 
                                                          tos, 
                                                          subject, 
                                                          "", 
                                                          body, 
                                                          false);  
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(message);  
    return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
}
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 12):

It turns out that there is a known bug in `Sendgrid`. If the html content entered is very big, the correct error message will not be sent. Instead, this error will show up. In my case, my `apiKey` was not found and I should therefore have gotten an `Unauthorized` error message. When I changed my html into one much smaller, this gave me the correct error.

Read more about the issue [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/648).

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly my issue. I had forgotten to add the APIKey to the Azure configuration for the azure function app, and the “Error while copying content to a stream” message put me on the wrong track.

Answer (score 4):

**I'm having the same problem**, but in my case it's because the email quota has expired (I'm using the free version for testing):
[image]

> Lib version 9.21.0

**On the mentioned thread** https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/648 some people were passing the `wrong apiKey`, and others `exceeding the HTML size`.

As said in the thread above, apparently it's a bug in the sendgrid library when interpreting the error.

**Therefore, in addition to the problems mentioned** (passing the wrong apiKey, exceeding the HTML size) the return *“Error while copying content to a stream”* is hiding other problems as well (like in my case: `quota expired`).